# Duvida - Função para Limpar img com javascript não funciona

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Preciso limpar um campo `img` e para isso estou utilizando o código abaixo, mas ao clicar no `button` o javascript não funciona por que a pagina recebe um refresh.

Analisei o console do navegador e não aparece nenhuma mensagem de erro... Podem me dizer aonde estou errando??

Aqui está o código do botão

```
   <?php
// verificando o diretorio utilizado para fins de desenvolvimento 
  diretorio();
  if(Empty($dir)){
    $img_padrao = '/images/sem_imagem.jpeg';
  }else{
    $img_padrao = '/'.$dir.'/images/sem_imagem.jpeg'; 
    }
  ?>                                  
  <img src='<?=$img_padrao?>' class='img-thumbnail limpar' id="img" alt="Img Destaque">                                


  <button id="apagar" onclick="clearimg('<?=$img_padrao?>')" class="btn btn-danger tabindex='4'">Remover Imagem</button>
```

aqui o javascript

```
// função responsavel por apagar a imagem do Box (exibir a imagem padrão).
function clearimg($img_padrao){
var clearimg = $img_padrao; 
$('.limpar').attr('src', clearimg);
}
```

Comment: Esse button está dentro de algum form? Tem que ser a tag button?

Comment: está dentro de um form sim, e não precisa ser a tag button

Comment: tu matou meu problema! mudei para input e funcionou... falta de experiência atrapalha e muito.. Obrigado! abraços!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provavelmente sua tag `button` está executando a ação padrão dela, além do evento `onclick`, que provavelmente é o submit em um formulário. Para evitar isso, você pode especificar o tipo de botão:

```
<button type="button">Botão</button>
```

Ou pode evitar a ação padrão retornando false na função do evento:

```
function acao() {
    return false;
}
```

Ou utilizar outra tag, como um `<input type="button">` ou `<a href="javascript:void(0);"></a>`.