# Javascript remove() não funciona

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Vejam o script abaixo. Por que ao clicar o `remove()` não funciona? eu recentemente postei nesse link: [post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/231681/duvida-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-para-limpar-img-com-javascript-n%C3%A3o-funciona/231688#231688) algo parecido, mas no outro caso,  o problema era por que o botão estava dentro de um form, mas dessa vez não tem form na pagina já mudei para `input <a href="#"></a> button`, mas nada funciona!

```
        function buscar(tamanho){
        var pasta = $('#pasta').val();  
        // utilizando o split para quebrar o diretorio e receber somente o nome da pasta
        var dirimg = pasta.split("/galeriaimg/");
        $.ajax({
            url: 'galeria.php?pasta=' + dirimg[1] + '&tamanho=' + tamanho,
            dataType: 'json',  

                success: function(result){ 

                   $.each(result, function(key, value){
                        var container = '<div class="col-md-4 id="col-'+key+'">';
                        container +=        '<div class="img-wrap">';
                        container +=            '<img src="/wpauditoria/images/'+tamanho+'/galeriaimg/'+dirimg[1]+'/'+value+'" class="img-return" alt="galeria" "/>';    
                        container +=            '<a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm delete" onclick="excluir('+key+')"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>'; 
                        container +=         '</div>';    

                        container +=         '<input type="hidden" name="imagemgaleria['+key+'][titulo]" value="/galeriaimg/'+dirimg[1]+'/'+value+'" />';    
                        container +=         '<input type="text" placeholder="Título" name="imagemgaleria['+key+'][titulo]" class="form-control inputgaleria" />';   
                        container +=         '<input type="text" placeholder="Link" name="imagemgaleria['+key+'][link]" class="form-control inputgaleria" />';   
                        container +=         '<textarea name="imagemgaleria['+key+'][descricao]" placeholder="Descricao" class="form-control inputgaleria" ></textarea>';   
                        container +=    '</div>';   

                        $('#galeriaimg').append(container);
                   });
             }
        });
    }

    function excluir(id){  
        console.log(id);  
        $("#col-"+id).remove();
}
```

Realizei um `console.log(id)` para ver se o id estava sendo repassado e essa parte funciona normalmente, a função recebe o ID mas não executa a instrução `$("#col-"+id).remove();` e também não retorna mensagem de erro.

Html

```
<body>

<!-- FORMULARIO HTML CADASTRO DE IMAGEMS -->
<div class="panel panel-primary panel-horizontal" style="margin-top: -19px;">
    <!-- div responsavel pela borda lateral.. e pelo conteudo se houver... -->
    <div class="panel-heading "></div>
    <div class="panel-body ">
        <!-- Container fluido para ajustar automaticamente o layout --> 
        <main role="main" class="container">
          <!-- Page Header -->
          <div class="page-header">
            <h2><a id="content">Inclusão de Galeria de Imagens no Site</a></h2>
            <div>Inclua uma Galeria para realizar uma transição de fotos para os seus usuários.</div>
          </div>

          <!-- tab da pagina -->
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Inclusao de Imagens</a></li>
          </ul>

          <!-- Classe Responsavel pelo tamanho e por centralizar do Panel -->
          <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-offset-2"> 

          <!-- Div responsavel pelo titulo em azul do form -->  
          <div class="page-header">
          <!-- Div responsavel por alinhar os panels  -->  
          <div class="panel-group">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                  <div class="panel-title text-center">Cadastro de Imagens</div>
                </div> 
              </div>

                <!-- div responsavel pelo panel lateral na horizontal -->
                <div class="panel panel-primary panel-horizontal">
                  <!-- div responsavel pela borda lateral.. e pelo conteudo se houver... -->
                  <div class="panel-heading"></div>
                    <!-- Classe Responsavel pelo conteudo do panel-->
                    <div class="panel-body">

                          <!-- Titulo-->
                          <div class="panel panel-primary">
                            <div class="panel-body">     
                                <div class="col-xs-5  col-md-7">
                                      <label for="titulo">Título:</label>
                                      <!-- Campo Pasta e Seleção de Imagens-->
                                      <div class="input-group text-center">
                                          <input type="text" placeholder="Título" name="titulo" id="titulo" class="form-control " value="">   
                                      </div> 
                                </div>      

                                <div class="col-xs-5  col-md-4">
                                      <label for="pasta">Pasta:</label>
                                      <!-- Campo Pasta e Seleção de Imagens-->
                                      <div class="input-group">
                                          <span clas="input-group-btn text-center">
                                            <a href=<?=(Empty($dir))?"/assets/libs/filemanager/dialog.php?type=2&field_id=pasta": "/".$dir."/assets/libs/filemanager/dialog.php?type=2?&field_id=pasta"?> class="btn btn-info fancy" data-fancybox-type="iframe">
                                                <i class="fa fa-folder-open-o"></i>
                                            </a>
                                          </span>                                     
                                          <input type="text" placeholder="Pasta" class="form-control" name="pasta" id="pasta" onchange="buscar('medium')" value="">   
                                      </div>                                         
                                </div> 


                                <!-- Div Responsável por exibir o conteudo da galeria de imagens -->   
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div id="galeriaimg">                        
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <?php
                                    // verificando o diretorio utilizado para fins de desenvolvimento 
                                    diretorio();
                                    if(Empty($dir)){
                                      $img_padrao = '/images/sem_imagem.jpeg';
                                    }else{
                                      $img_padrao = '/'.$dir.'/images/sem_imagem.jpeg'; 
                                    }
                                ?>

                                <div class="text-center">
                                   <input type="button" value="Limpar Imagem" onclick="clearimg('<?=$img_padrao?>')" class="btn btn-danger text-center oculto">             
                                </div>
                               </div>    

                            </div>                            
                    </div> <!-- Panel body -->
                </div> <!-- Panel horizontal -->

                    <!-- Campo Botão Cadastrar --> 

                    <div class="panel panel-primary panel-horizontal">
                      <!-- div responsavel pela borda lateral.. e pelo conteudo se houver... -->
                      <div class="panel-heading "></div>
                        <div class="panel-body ">
                            <button type="Submit" name="cadastrar" id="cadastrar" value="cadastrar" onclick="window.onbeforeunload = null;" class="btn btn-primary center-block oculto">Cadastrar</button>
                        </div>
                      </div>   





                <!-- Botao de Paginacao -->           
                <ul class="pager">
                  <li class="previous col"><a href="galeriaimg.php">Voltar</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>

    </div>
    </div><!-- panel group -->
    </div> <!-- pagheader -->
    </div><!-- /.col-sm-8 -->
```

Print do Alert confirmando o recebimento do ID

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Print do Elemento do Console, o Id também é repassado!
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Posta aí o HTML que vc tá usando.

Comment: onde você ta chamando a função excluir?

Comment: @haykou no href que tem no codigo

Comment: @DavidSamm , html postado, abs

Comment: Ixi! Não vi nada chamando a função `excluir().`

Comment: @DavidSamm to chamando no codigo do ajax, nessa parte `container +=            '<a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm delete" onclick="excluir('+key+')"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>';`

Comment: Ah tah rs.. não tinha visto

Comment: @DiegoLela e a sua função buscar está funcionando?

Comment: @haykou está sim! exibe as imagens só o botão excluir que não funciona! complementando, ele até funciona exibe o id, mas a parte onde está o remove() não limpa a div

Comment: Veja se no console a `'<div class="col-md-4 id="col-'+key+'">';` está passando o valor `key` corretamente nessa div.

Comment: @DiegoLela e onde tá a div com id col ?

Comment: Vamos supor que essa `key` seja "10", veja se no console a div criada aparece `'<div class="col-md-4 id="col-10">';`. Pode ser que esteja indo vazia, aí a função `excluir()` não tá encontrando nada.

Comment: Bota um `console.log(key)` abaixo da linha `$.each(result, function(key, value){` pra ver se esse valor `key` está passando corretamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma sugestão também para deixar seu código mais limpo:

E vez de vc concatenar as linhas repetindo a variável `container`, basta botar um `+` no início de cada linha, e só colocar `;` no final da última.

Em vez de:

```
var container = '<div class="col-md-4" id="col-'+key+'">';
container +=        '<div class="img-wrap">';
```

**Usar:**

```
var container = '<div class="col-md-4" id="col-'+key+'">'
+'<div class="img-wrap">'
....
+'</div>';
```

Comment: obrigado pela dica! esses detalhes são bem valiosos para quem tá no começo! =]

Answer (score 2):

Obrigado pela ajuda @haykou e @DavidSamm

O problema estava no seguinte trecho

```
<div class="col-md-4" id="col-'+key+'">';
```

estava faltando uma aspas duplas no final do `"col-md-4"`por isso que a instrução não funcionava!

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que eu vi o seu código está certo mas tá faltando passar o elemento correto no **remove**, segue um exemplo do que você está fazendo abaixo:

```
<div id="app">
 <div class="teste"></div>
 <div id="col-1">hello</div>
</div>
```

**js**

```
 function buscar(){
      var teste = '<a onclick="excluir(1)">ok</a>';
   $('#app').append(teste);
 }

    function excluir(id){  
       alert('ok');
      $('#col-'+id).remove();
}

buscar(1);
```

Ao clicar no **a**, ele executa a função excluir normalmente.

Comment: Isso não responde a pergunta. Vc apenas postou um exemplo simples que funciona desconsiderando o código dele. Como ele disse na pergunta, o código está indo corretamente para a função `excluir()`. O problema deve estar no código dentro do Ajax quando ele cria o elemento de forma dinâmica.

Comment: @DavidSamm to atualizando o post com um alert e com o console 1 minuto

Comment: @DavidSamm você achou o elemento com id = col ?

Comment: Sim, dentro do Ajax: `var container = '<div class="col-md-4 id="col-'+key+'">';`

Comment: @DavidSamm pelo print me parece que tem um espaço entre as aspas e o col...

Comment: mas no meu código não tem  esse espaço! =/

Comment: obrigado pessoal era erro ali mesmo! faltava uma aspas duplas"

Comment: Isso mesmo! Aspas dupla depois de col-md-4.